# Where does rpm look for dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, rpm

I have an rpm which I have build using rpmbuild. Lets say it is sample.rpm.
It builds successfully. The rpm has and executable (let's call it init).

When I try to install it using `rpm -ivh sample.rpm` it shows me failed dependencies.

Let's say the error is `Failed dependency for: example.so` which means that rpm is not able to locate this shared object file. (even though the so file exists in the same directory).

So, I install the rpm as `rpm -ivh sample.rpm --nodeps` (as I know that I have the required so files).

Why is rpm not able to install those rpms then?
where does it look for the object files? (does the linux loader looks for these .so). I have LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include path to these .so and so when I run the installed file (init) from the rpm it runs.

Then why is rpm not able to install sample.rpm (where exactly does it look for dependencies)?
Is it something that needs to be specified at the time when the rpm is build?

Answer (score 16):

The dependencies of an RPM file are specified in its `.spec` file on the "Requires:" line.

#### Sample SPEC file:

```sh
Summary: <Summary for my Linux project>
Name: <Name for my Linux project>
Version: 2.5.1
Release: GA
Requires: libx1.so >= 2.6.3
BuildArch: i586
Group: System / Applications
License: GPL 2.0
Vendor: <my organization>
```

You can also run this command to determine which dependencies are required:

```sh
$ rpm -q --requires <my_rpm>
libx1.so.2
$
```

The dependency `libx1.so` itself should be installed through an RPM, so that its presence is entered in a database maintained by the RedHat Package Manager. In other words, the physical presence of `libx1.so` on the file system is not the criteria for the dependency test.

To find out which package provides the dependency, run the command:

```sh
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libx1
```

If no package provides `libx1.so`, your RPM will continue to show a dependency error unless you remove `libx1.so` from the "Requires:" line.

To disable automatic detection of dependencies, you can add this to your `.spec` file:

```sh
AutoReqProv: no
```

A lot more information is at [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html) and [rpm5.org](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/dependencies.html).

Comment: I also advice to use yum to install your rpm packages. When distributing packages you usually provide an rpm that adds a yum repo source pointing to your repository and then your customers can use `yum install product` and later on `yum update product`.