# Disable rpmbuild automatic requirement finding

Tags: centos, packaging, rpm, rpmbuild

The default behavior of rpmbuild seems to be to scan every file in the buildroot for #! lines and add those interpreters as hard requirements. Is it possible to disable this? I've run into a situation where people are committing scripts with #!/path/to/local/install/of/something and that requirement is becoming embedded in the rpm.

I haven't been able to find a command line or spec file option that suppresses this behavior. Hopefully I just didn't look hard enough.

Comment: So you want to package script files that *won't work* on the target machine?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Yes, exactly.  Well, I don't specifically /want/ to package them, but it would be too difficult to prune them all. It's harmless if they end up on the target machine. I don't want the presence of them to stop the install from succeeding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the question has an answer in [Where does rpm look for dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418814/where-does-rpm-look-for-dependencies). At least `AutoReqProv: no` disables scanning and then you would need manual `Requires: xxx` values; not the least work solution, but a solution. I would also guess that something like *.rpmmacros* has a way to disable the script scanning. Take a look at `/usr/lib/rpm/find-requires`.

Comment: I already had all the Requires: I needed, so AutoReqProv: no was the missing piece of the puzzle.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`__provides_exclude_from`, `__provides_exclude`, `__requires_provides_from` and `__requires_provides` also works in Fedora / Centos / RHEL

`%global __provides_exclude_from %{buildroot}%{_javadir}/%{name}/lib/`

where `%{buildroot}%{_javadir}/%{name}/lib/` is one directory

a more complex example :

```
# Filter away the deps om bundled libs and those substituted
# by symlinks and explicit Requires:.

%global __requires_exclude                     ^libssl.so.1.0.0
%global __requires_exclude %__requires_exclude|^libcrypto.so.1.0.0
%global __requires_exclude %__requires_exclude|^libcef.so
%global __requires_exclude %__requires_exclude|^libcurl.so.4
%global __requires_exclude %__requires_exclude|^libcurl-gnutls.so.4
%global __requires_exclude %__requires_exclude|^libwidevinecdm.so.*
#global __requires_exclude #__requires_exclude|[.]so[.][0-2][a-f]
```