# RPM .spec file, disable generation of Java dependencies

Tags: java, rpm

I'm packaging a java project on RHEL 7 , and it seems rhe RPN packaging automatically adds
dependencies it discovers in some of the .jar files, e.g. like:

```
$ rpm -qp --requires pdi-ce-8.3.0.0.371-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
osgi(org.codehaus.janino.commons-compiler)
osgi(org.eclipse.core.commands)
osgi(org.eclipse.core.filesystem)
osgi(org.eclipse.core.resources)
osgi(org.eclipse.core.runtime)
osgi(org.eclipse.equinox.common)
osgi(org.eclipse.swt)
osgi(org.eclipse.text)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

The references to osgi are not listed in the .spec file, and I would like to disable the automatically generation of these dependencies, how can it be done ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable rpmbuild automatic requirement finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598201/disable-rpmbuild-automatic-requirement-finding)

Comment: Somewhat. It disables all automatically generated dependencies - which works for now, but I'd like a btter solution where only the java deependencies could be diabled.

Comment: disabling generation of only part of the automatic dependencies is not possible IMO